# using LinqToSql with OData WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, odata

We have a project that uses `LinqToSql` as its `ORM` and We'd like to expose our entities using `OData` version 4 (thus as far as I have learned we can't use `WCF Data Services` and we should use `Web Api` instead).

So far I couldn't find any example or documentation on the Net that shows how to use `LinqToSql` along with `OData WebApi`.

The problem is `ODataConventionModelBuilder` works with `EntityFramework` ( Actually it default set of conventions works with `DataComponentModel` annotations which are not used in our `LinqToSql` entities)

I am looking for a `ODataModelBuilder` that works with `System.Data.Linq.Mapping` to make the model.

The other solution is to find the correct set of conventions for `ODataConventionModelBuilder` that works with `LinqToSql` mapping annotatoins.

I don't know if this model builder exists or should we implement it ourselves ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no off-the-shelf model builder for Linq to SQL. There are several different ways you can solve your problem.

- Derive from `ODataModelBuilder` a custom builder class that recognizes the annotations defined in `System.Data.Linq.Mapping`.
- [Build the model manually](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#02-02-model-builder-untyped) using the methods of the stock `ODataModelBuilder`.
- Build a set of data transfer classes that represent the exact types and properties you want to expose through your service, and then write a utility for transforming data transfer objects to data storage objects, and vice versa. In the data transfer layer, the classes can adhere to the conventions recognized by `ODataConventionModelBuilder` (e.g., key properties are named `Id` or `FooId` for a class named `Foo`). The transformation utility can be written easily with the help of a library like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). See [ASP.NET WebApi OData support for DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962081/asp-net-webapi-odata-support-for-dtos), [DTO and Projections in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160574/dto-and-projections-in-webapi), and [Web API Deep Dive - DTO Transformations and Automapper](http://codethug.com/2015/02/13/web-api-deep-dive-dto-transformations-and-automapper-part-5-of-6/).

Comment: What do you mean by "stock ODataModelBuilder" ?

Comment: I just mean the existing `ODataModelBuilder` class, which requires you to build your model explicitly. E.g, `builder.EntityType<Foo>().HasKey(f  => f.FooID)`, etc. Rather than relying on a set of conventions that can discover the types, properties, and relationships in your data model, you must manually specify all of that information.